# Converting every two elements of a list to CSV in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists like the following one:

```
[[5, 6], [10, 11], [14, 15]]
```

I want to output them as a csv file maybe using pandas to_csv in the following format:

```
Start End
5     6
10    11
14    15
```

How can I do this? I have an idea of flattening the list and then making every two elements as a comma-separated line of a CSV file. But I think it can be done more easily.

Comment: So you want comma-separated or tab-separated? Your question and output example don't match.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @matszwecja Any one of them would work. That doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use pandas you can use:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(data_list, columns=["start","end"])
data.to_csv("myfile.csv")
```

Comment: Wow, that was freaking easy. I don't know why I thought it in a complicated way.